# Is it possible to implement η-reduction in interaction nets?

Tags: lambda-calculus, computer-science, lo.logic, linear-logic

There are several ways to encode λ-terms in interaction nets; for instance, using [the original optimal algorithm](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.90.2386) by Lamping, or [compiling λ-calculus into interaction combinators](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.22.9699). However, all the encodings we know implement only β-reduction, and not extensional λ-calculus (with η-reduction as well).

**Is it possible to encode λ-terms into interaction nets implementing βη-reduction?**

(The normal form of a net for a term should correspond to the βη-normal form of the term if any.)